# Use of "dar" at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar-identification

Please explain the use of "dar" in this sentence:

> Dieser Impfstoff kommt jetzt aber auch nicht und jetzt steht die EU eben größtenteils leer dar.

The verb is printed as "stehen" not "stellen" and the last word is "dar" not "da".

I am unable to locate "darstehen" in any dictionary.

Comment: Most probably a typo.

Comment: The whole wording sounds strange ... shouldn't it be »und jetzt steht die EU eben mit größtenteils leeren Händen da.« (oder so)?

Comment: As Hubert said, this is most likely a typo. A example of correct usage of "dar" would be *"Er stellte sich als ein guter Schüler dar."* (from "darstellen"). Other verbs that could be used like that would be "darbieten" or "darlegen".

Comment: That seems to be a transskript of some spoken text on https://www.newsinslowgerman.com . Half correct phrases can happen more often in public talks, because otherwise people would contantly have to correct themselves. The "dar" in the end might be the fault of a speech-to-text software or the person who typed it had a glitch happening.

Comment: Tippfehler sind Fehler, die entstehen, wenn der Finger danebenhaut, abgleitet, die Taste prellt oder hakt. Nicht, wenn man ein Zeichen, dass da nicht hingehört hinschreibt. Das mag ein Flüchtigkeitsfehler sein, eine vorlaute Rechtschreibprüfung, oder eine spontane, geistige Umnachtung.

Comment: @userunknown: "Tippfehler sind Fehler, die entstehen, wenn der Finger danebenhaut, abgleitet, die Taste prellt oder hakt." - oder man zusammen mit der eigentlich gemeinten Taste noch eine andere drückt - entweder mit demselben Finger direkt daneben, oder mit einem anderen unglücklich tief platzierten Finger derselben Hand eine ganz andere Taste, was dann genau so ein Zeichen erzeugt, was da nicht hingehört.

Comment: @Raketenolli: Es wäre zu vermuten, dass der Sprecher sich nicht zwischen deiner Formulierung und "geht ... leer aus" entscheiden konnte, bis es bereits zu spät und der Satzanfang gesprochen war.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ja, oder in Indonesien hat ein Schmetterling mit dem Flügel gewackelt - schon klar. Natürlich kann ich einen Tippfehler nicht 100% ausschließen, aber die Annahme, es sei ein solcher, wäre gewagt. Ich denke Heinzi hat sich einfach noch nie gründlich gefragt, was ein Typo ist, und heftet das Wort nachlässig allen möglichen, kleinen Fehlern an. Er ist da nicht der Einzige. Ist ja auch schneller getippt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Es geht doch hier ganz offensichtlich um den Unterschied zwischen *stellt dar* und *steht da*. Das ist dann eben nicht einer dieser Tippfehler, sondern  - wie *userunknown* das m.E. ganz richtig anmerkt - dieser kurze Moment geistiger Umnachtung, den wir doch alle kennen (oder?), von dem ich mich jedenfalls weder freisprechen kann noch will.

Answer (score 18):

It just is a typo. It is wrong.

The correct version is:

> Dieser Impfstoff kommt jetzt aber auch nicht und jetzt steht die EU eben größtenteils leer **da.**

Comment: It's the grammatically correct version. "Die EU steht größtenteils leer da" is still a patently absurd phrasing of course.

Comment: Tippfehler sind Fehler, die entstehen, wenn der Finger danebenhaut, abgleitet, die Taste prellt oder hakt. Nicht, wenn man ein Zeichen, dass da nicht hingehört hinschreibt. Das mag ein Flüchtigkeitsfehler sein, eine vorlaute Rechtschreibprüfung, oder eine spontane, geistige Umnachtung.

Comment: Ich muss @userunknown hier einfach vollkommen recht geben (oder heißt es Recht geben?). Tippfehler erklärt es einfach nicht. Es geht um *dar* oder *da*. Das ist selbst bei professionellen Schreibern (tagesschau.de) gar nicht so selten.

Comment: @userunknown: Ich schreibe sehr sehr oft »sit«, »begen« und »Moant« wenn ich eigentlich »ist«, »geben« oder »Monat« schreiben will. Da haut kein Finger daneben und da prellt oder hakt auch keine Taste. Oder: Wenn ich das Wort »kein« schreiben will, schreibe ich stattdessen oft »keine«. Das sind alles Fehler, bei denen ich mich vertippt habe, also Tippfehler. Und wenn jemand, der »dar« anstelle von »da« schreibt, ist das dieselbe Fehlerart. ...

Comment: ... Siehe auch [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tippfehler): *»Ein Tippfehler ist ein unerkannt gebliebener Rechtschreibfehler bei maschinengeschriebenen Texten, der nicht durch Unkenntnis der richtigen Schreibweise entstanden ist, sondern durch mangelnde Konzentration bei der Texteingabe mittels Tastatur.«* Das Kriterium ist die mangelnde Konzentration, nicht die mangelhafte Feinmotorik der Finger oder ein Hardwarefehler in der Tastatur.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Meine Aufzählung war illustrativ gemeint, ohne Anspruch auf Vollständigkeit. Ich weiß nicht wieso Du "keine" schreibst, wenn Du "kein" meinst". "Mangelnde Konzentration" beschreibt eben Flüchtigkeitsfehler, nicht nur Tippfehler, die natürlich eine echte Teilmenge der Flüchtigkeitsfehler sind. Solange Du nicht selbst darjenige bist, der sich vertippt hat, kannst Du bei anderen nicht entscheiden, ob es ein Tippfehler war. Die Wikipediadefinition gibt eine notwendige, aber keine hinreichende Definition und ist nicht autoritativ.